# how to cross-reference a theorem

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, theorems

I have written a theorem like this in latex
\begin{theorem}
lllllll
\end{theorem}
I would like when I cite this theorem I found ''theorem 5.2'' written in blue and by clicking on this I go to the desired theorem.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! See the `cleveref` and `hyperref` packages, and possibly `thmtools`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  For future questions, it's a bit more helpful if you also include the minimal working example to create that theorem.  Just by itself, LaTeX doesn't have a `theorem` environment.  But there are several common packages that create that environment.  On the other hand, Bernard's suggestion will work with any of those common packages.

Answer (score 3):

You need to load a package, say `amsthm` or `ntheorem`, to simplify setting up theorem-like environment. To make cross-reference call-outs into blue hyperlinks, you need to load the `hyperref` package with the options `colorlinks` and `linkcolor=blue`. I also recommend you load the `cleveref` package with the option `nameinlink`. Then, associate a `\label` directive with each theorem you wish to cross-reference, and create cross-reference call-outs with `\cref` and/or `\autoref` statements.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage[colorlinks,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}
% Set up theorem-like environments:
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}
\counterwithin{theorem}{section} % just for this example
\setcounter{section}{5} \stepcounter{theorem}

\begin{theorem} \label{thm:important}
Bla bla bla
\end{theorem}

\noindent
A cross-reference to \autoref{thm:important}.
Another cross-reference to \cref{thm:important}.

\end{document}
```